# How to display image in mail header using wp_mail()

Tags: images, wp-mail

How to display image in email header. I tried below, it in gmail it is not displaying the image. Please any one help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

```
    $to = $_REQUEST['userEmail'];
    $firstName = $_REQUEST['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_REQUEST['lastName'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $question = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = 'Test Email';
    $message = "<html><head><img src='http://192.168.1.157/Shop/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/image_nmae.png'/></head>"
            . "<body><h1>Visitor Information</h1>"
            . "<p>Visitor Information: Fist Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$firstName."&nbsp;&nbsp; Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; ".$lastName."</p>"
            . "<p>Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$email."</p><p>Question:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$question."</p></body></html>";
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $mailSend = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

The email header is not the same as the `<head>` of an HTML document (even if that document is an email).  So the question shouldn't be how to display an image in the email header because the answer is that you can't.

Second, the same thing holds true for an HTML document. The `<head>` section (where the `<img>` tag is currently located in the OP) is for holding information about the document, and what is contained in there will not be displayed.

Since the `<img>` tag in the `<head>` location will not be displayed, the problem is simply malformed HTML. To display, the `<img>` must be inside the `<body>` tag somewhere.

```
$to = $_REQUEST['userEmail'];
$firstName = $_REQUEST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_REQUEST['lastName'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$question = $_POST['message'];
$subject = 'Test Email';
$message = "<html><head></head><body><img src='http://192.168.1.157/Shop/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/image_nmae.png'/>"
        . "<h1>Visitor Information</h1>"
        . "<p>Visitor Information: Fist Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$firstName."&nbsp;&nbsp; Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; ".$lastName."</p>"
        . "<p>Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$email."</p><p>Question:&nbsp;&nbsp;".$question."</p></body></html>";
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$mailSend = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your `$headers` before the form.
Also parse `$headers` like this

```
$headers .= 
"Content-Type: text/html; 
charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```